# Dynamics 365, UCI - Can't find a way to edit new form behaviors

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

With the dynamics 365 version 9.1, Microsoft introduces a hybrid version. Current customers are trying the new interface and starting to encounter bugs with our connector.

I can't find myself a way to modify the behavior of forms in UCI.

Our solution include a contact and an account form. In this form, we added fields and webresources icons.

Example of issue : I don't want phone fields to have a phone icon. Instead, I want my solution icon to be shown.

[image: Phone fields UCI issue]

As you can see, the phone fields in UCI add phone icon and push mine down the form.

Can we modify form and behavior in the new interface (UCI)?

**UPDATE : I took the problem in the wrong way. Instead of trying to remove the phone call icon from the UCI form and replace it with my own custom button i should have registered to the events directly.
If you want to register to the phonecall icon events you will need to implement the Channel Integration Framework into your solution.**

[CIF General documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/channel-integration-framework/channel-integration-framework)

[CIF Events documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/channel-integration-framework/reference/events/onclicktoact)

Comment: Are you saying what you were able to achieve in Classic UI is impossible now in UCI? can you add screenshot?

Comment: Hello @ArunVinoth, i added further information to my question and a picture to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this good to have feature cannot be turned off it seems. “Click to dial” option with a phone icon is showing next to textbox control when there is a valid phone number in phone number field to allow you to use/call in single click via Skype, Jabber, etc.

Even email address fields showing “mailto:” option with an icon next to the field control. These are fixed layouts, generated dynamically & not customizable as of today.

May be you added your own icon using iframe/webresource (you didn’t show how it looks in web UI), but layout is rendering in different order in UCI (pushing your icon down). You can do some unsupported alternate workaround but it’s not recommended.

Comment: You answered my question perfectly. I really appreciate that you take time for that. I suspected it that the current version do not allowed to modify the Click to dial option and more generally the behavior of UCI forms. I guess we have to wait now. Thank you Arun!